# MySQL Query to Search on Main Table and "Child" Table

Tags: mysql

```
* forum
forum_id
forum_subject
forum_description

* forum_message
forum_message_id
forum_id
forum_message_description
```

I'm looking to have a search by a keyword that it will search on the forum_subject and on the forum_message_description

I came up with the obvious:

```
SELECT forum_subject, forum_description, forum_id FROM forum WHERE forum_subject LIKE '%keyword%'
```

But I can't seem to figure it out how to search on the same query on the forum_message and return the information only from the forum table... maybe a subselect?

Thanks for your help

Comment: Have you got two tables ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are looking for is a FULL OUTER JOIN, but sadly, MySQL does not directly support such a command. It can be emulated, however, using a UNION.

```
SELECT forum.forum_id,forum.forum_subject,forum.forum_description
FROM forum 
WHERE forum.subject LIKE '%keyword%'

UNION

SELECT forum.forum_id,forum.forum_subject,forum.forum_description
FROM forum
INNER JOIN forum_message ON forum_message.forum_message_id = forum.id
WHERE forum_message.forum_message_description LIKE '%keyword%'
```

The first query will return your results from the forum table, filtered by the subject column. The second query will also return results from the forum table, but filtered by a matching row from the forum_message table that has a forum_message_description similar to your keywords. The UNION command combines rows from both queries and removes the duplicates.

Comment: Thank you! That does the trick! And that was a great explanation as well! Thanks